# Problem with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem with the file `application.properties`, in this line :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

when I delete some attributes from my entity, these attributes still remain in the database.

This is a copy of application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskmanagement
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
server.port=89
spring.data.rest.default-media-type= application/json
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: problem is not with properties

Comment: You cannot. `update` will only add new columns and constraints. It won't remove columns, constraints etc. Also you really shouldn't be using `update` or `create` for anything other then tests, for real db management you want to use something like Flyway or LiquiBase instead.

Comment: Reliable database update can't be achieved by Hibernate AFAIK. Tools like Flyway or Liquidbase are designed for database migration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to recreate your database schema based on object mapping, simply use:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

However remember, that this will destroy data you have saved in your database.

Other option would be to use `create-drop` - this will destroy your database schema on application termination.

Edit:

You cannot update your database schema without destroying the data. Imagine you're changing datatype of some field and already have data. Database doesn't know how to convert existing data.

Comment: yes, i know that, but i don't want to drop the information in all the database, for that i can't use create-drop.

i think that there is a problem with this line : spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: yes, i understand this, i work with one empty table in the database, when i delete a attribute from my entity this attribut stay remains in this empty table. my problem is  if i use create-drop, all the information in the others tables will be destroy.

Comment: what do you want EXACTLY?

Comment: when i delete an attribut from my entity, this attribut will be remove from the database.(i work with empty table)

Comment: and what's wrong with my answer? can't you use `create`?

Answer (score 1):

The `update` value for the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` only tries to add new columns and constraints. It does not remove existing columns from the table. Try using `create` or `create-drop`

Comment: yes, i know that, but i don't want to drop the information in all the database, for that i can't use create-drop. i think that there is a problem with this line : spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Copying the same comment from the other answer will help. As mentioned by this answer (and my comment) `update` will only add new column and constraints. It will not change datatypes or drop columns. So you don't know that (as you assumed it will).

Comment: @MohamedDhia So you want to delete the columns associated with the removed attributes from the table but not delete any other information from other tables within the database? There is no way to do this using the ddl-auto property. If the columns are no longer needed, you can manually delete them from the table. This should not cause any issues in the execution of the program if the attributes do not exist